# Repeat last normal mode command, including moves, in Vim

Tags: vim, text-editors, normal-mode

In Vim, with `.`, I can repeat the last normal mode command; for example:

```
dd.
```

deletes a line twice.
But, if I type

```
5j.
```

the cursor does't move 10 lines down. How do I repeat the last normal mode command, especially a move?

Comment: why don't you accept one of the answers below ? you forgot about it, or there's a reason ?

Answer (score 50):

it's doable even in vanilla vim, but applicability depends on your use case, ie. how often you'll need to repeat it, since it requires few more keystrokes to make it repeatable.

---

### Option 1: turn it into a command mode operation

using moving down 5 lines as example, you can do:

1. enter `:norm 5j`, it'll move the cursor down 5 lines
2. use `@:` to repeat the movement

`:norm` stands for normal, any following string is regarded as your keystrokes under normal mode

---

### Option 2: Use macro

1. `qa` (store macro into register `a`, you can pick your own register like `qb`, `qc`)
2. `5j`
3. `q` (finish recording macro)
4. `@a` to repeat your recorded operation (replace `a` with the register name you picked, eg. `@b`, `@c`)

macro requires more spiritual power to set up but it's more repeatable in the sense that you can store multiple operations in different registers without being overriden by latest operations.

Comment: This should be the right answer!

Comment: Option 2 all the way! Don't forget you can also re-run the last macro with `@@`. Also, I usually use the q register so the keyflow becomes `qq5jq`, `@@`.

Comment: I've incorporated this and another answer, thus totalling it to 3 ways, over [here for "Vim: Repeat previous motion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778797/) at Stack Overflow. @JustinWrobel thanks for showing `@@`.

Answer (score 15):

`vim` doesn't do this unfortunately.  The best you can do is install the [repmo.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174) plugin, which repeats movement commands that have a count.

Comment: I love repmo, but I've not got it to work with ggandor/leap.nvim.

Do you have a solution to this, or a more recent alternative?

Answer (score 11):

You can repeat changes with `.`.  Movements can be repeated with the `;` command.  This command seems to be new and does a similar thing to the repmo.vim script mentioned in other answers.

For example, to move to the second next `c`, press `2fc`.  Then to do it again, just type `;`.

Comment: `;` isn't new. It's a standard vi command. Vi remembers the type and target character (but not numerical argument) of the last `f`/`F`/`t`/ `T` motion and `;` repeats it. It doesn't repeat other motions, however.

Comment: This accomplished what I was looking to do! thank you. and thank you @pyrocrasty for the clarification!

Comment: @pyrocrasty Yes, showing that this is strictly limited to just those motions and can't do more needs to be shown in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Actually `.` repeats the last **change**, not the last normal mode command.  As Paul said, you will need a plugin to allow you to repeat motions.

See "`:help .`".

Answer (score 0):

You can select the lines you want to change and execute last normal dot command

```
v5j .............. visual select next 5 lines
:'<,'>norm! .      normal mode execute over selection last command '.'
```